# How use walletconnect for tokens transaction

Tags: wallet, erc20, decentralized-applications

I'm using wallet connect for Eth transaction in my app.
but now need transact an ERC-20 token and don't know how do that

Answer (score 0):

It has passed 8 months, but I'll answer.

You need to first approve on the sender side and do the transaction later. WalletConnect only uses Mainnet, so test it using https://test.walletconnect.org/ or first work on the Metamask testnets and apply to Walletconnect